how much detail is needed to be given for a dating app that can take human written text and return matches from that?
ChatGPT is out.
Google has gemini.
I've already seen one failed dating app startup that takes freestyle human input, such as text, and then return a list of suggested matches to the user.
If an invention has as one of its many components a template to input by the user what kind of a person that they are looking for, and one of the input options is free text input which would be processed by an AI in the back end server, how much detail do I need to give to enable this component of the invention?
This component is not the main idea or novel step of the invention. It is already being done. And actually, it is an optional feature, as there are many other ways to specify who is a match, such as traditional filters.
The invention is a greater whole involving many components and steps, and the combination of these steps and components is the inventive step.
So the question is:

How much detail do I need to include for the processing of the freestyle human input?
Do I need to say any more than just that? In other words, "the template includes a text widget for the user to input freestyle text to describe in their own words who they would like to match with, which would be part of the input to the matchmaker operating on the server that contains an AI component that can process freestyle, unstructured inputs."



ChatGPT is out. Google has gemini.

As far as I know these are proprietary models/technologies that are not fully publicly available, so they don't directly help with enablement. However, for the purposes of this answer let us assume that there are equivalent open source softwares that are publicly available and can be used to satisfy the enablement requirement.

how much detail do I need to give to enable this component of the invention?

Even if we assume that it is enabled, you must still give sufficient detail to render the claim(s) definite and establish the metes and bounds of the invention. Many claims are excessively functional and while they might meet enablement because they can be implemented using technology that is commonly available at the time of filing, they do not necessarily define an invention sufficiently precisely.
Specifically in computer-implemented inventions the gold standard is to have an algorithm, or stepwise breakdown of a process that can be computer-implemented. Courts have stated that where there is no algorithm, the claim "amounts to impermissible pure functional claiming". As it stands, one cannot claim a general-purpose computer plus a functionality without reference to a specific implementation.

In other words, "the template includes a text widget for the user to input freestyle text to describe in their own words who they would like to match with, which would be part of the input to the matchmaker operating on the server that contains an AI component that can process freestyle, unstructured inputs."

These days, you won't get far with a claim that includes a blackbox "AI component" that appears to do all the work and is nowhere described how it works.
However, if, as you say, the AI is not central to your invention it is entirely possible to get a generic comprising claim that would encompass the base invention combined with an arbitrary unspecified AI component (that is not recited in the claim).
